# Why do I get a "TCP Retransmission" right after having sent a packet?

Tags: networking, tcp, mqtt

I have a program (in Python) that publishes information to a bus (MQTT, implemented by `mosquitto`). This is a "fire and forget" kind of message, that is there is no long term subscription, just a message sent.

All this works, but I noticed (by chance) that the TCP traffic is strange:

[image]

`192.168.10.2` is a server, on which `172.19.0.20` is a docker container with the MQTT server. The command was `tcpdump -i any port 1883 -w mqtt.pcap`. These two lines are the only ones for each transmission (for each publication to the MQTT bus).

Why could be the reason for this `TCP Retransmission`? (everything works overall, I am just curious why the retransmission)

Comment: How did you do this capture, exactly?

Comment: @Spiff oh sorry, I forgot to provide it - I updated the question.

Comment: Did you ever learn anything about this? We are seeing similar behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

The reliable service of TCP requires that all segments containing data be acknowledged by the receiver. When an acknowledgment (ACK) for a segment is not received, the sender must retransmit the segment.

For each connection, TCP maintains a variable called the retransmission time-out (RTO), which is the amount of time within which an ACK for the segment is expected. If TCP does not receive an ACK before the RTO expires, the segment is retransmitted.

Please refer to the following article:

https://www.extrahop.com/company/blog/2016/retransmission-timeouts-rtos-application-performance-degradation/

Comment: Thanks. What actually worries me is that the retransmission is instantaneous, without waiting for the ACK